# Eliminate gap between tbody tags

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to eliminate the *slight* gap between two `tbody` tags when they are both displayed inline like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kttss/

[image: what the html renders]

As you can see in the fiddle, in between the two tables there is a slight gap. I know I can get rid of this manually by using negative margin, but this seems like a hassle since I have a table with a variable number of `tbody`s.

```
<table style="margin:0;" border="1">
   <tbody  style="display: inline-block;  margin:0;">
      <tr>
         <td>
            1
         </td>
         <td>
            2
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            3
         </td>
         <td>
            4
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody  style="display: inline-block; margin: 0;">
      <tr>
         <td>
            1
         </td>
         <td>
            2
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            3
         </td>
         <td>
            4
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's interesting. Your picture doesn't really display the problem, but it is apparent in your fiddle

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need two inline `tbody`s? Why not put them into one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like adding `border-spacing: 0;` to your `table` elements will help. Without this, there's 2 pixels surrounding each of the borders, which means there's 4 pixels between the tables.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kttss/8/) for your answer. I believe you should still remove/comment out the white-space between tbody(ies) or float the elements, as even though your fiddle works nicely in Chrome, Firefox renders a space between the tbodies. +1 anyway for the nice addition.

Answer (score 4):

Use float instead of `inline-block` display. You also have to collapse the borders with `border-collapse:collapse`, or use `border-spacing: 0` as in @JoeEnos's answer, as well.

```
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
tbody { float:left; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kttss/9/)

With `display: inline-block`, the white-space in the markup (line-breaks, tabs) are collapsed and rendered as a single space. `float`s are not affected by this.

Comment: Although it isn't necessary to collapse the borders, it does give it a more unified look

Comment: @CodyGuldner Yes, without collapsing, there's a weird padding between the table and the `tbody`(ies). `=]` Well, `border-spacing:0` also fixes this particular issue as in @Joe's answer.