# Exact height on table row <tr>

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm struggling to set an **EXACT** height on a html table-row.

[image: Example]

The left column are two divs of height 44px each, and the right column is the table. The height of each row is set to 44px but rows are displayed as 44.44px in height on Google Chrome web inspection tool.

**SASS:**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  tr {
    height: 44px;
    cursor: pointer;
    td {
      padding: 0 16px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $bg-light;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm also using [Eric Meyers css-reset](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/), although the problem remains with or without it.

Any clues on where the extra .44px comes from?

**EDIT**

Problem seems to be specific to Google Chrome. Safari renders the correct height.

Comment: You are nesting your css. It should be `table{...}` `tr{...}` `td{...}`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear on that I'm using SASS

Comment: Could you add the HTML and the processed CSS so we can see the problem in the question? (create a [mcve]). That way, it would be easier for us to replicate and find a solution to the problem.

Comment: What about showing the HTML so we can reproduce your image state?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Eliminate gap between tbody tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458491/eliminate-gap-between-tbody-tags)

but, this is a border-collapse, border-spacing issue with your table next to your div. By default tables have that annoying extra space there. Also make sure that your td's and divs are display inline-block/block or flex if you want to align items in the center.

here's some code and a link for how to resolve it.

```
table {
   border-spacing: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

https://codepen.io/calebswank11/pen/rJvBWK